# parse android upload and download

Tags: java, android

i am using the services of parse.com, android guide:

https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide

and it  didnt work for me (i get a message: app must be closed...)

here is my code:

```
gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
try {
    gameScore.save();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        //  Access the object id here
          objectId= gameScore.getObjectId();
      }
    });

ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("GameScore");

query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback() {

@Override
public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int score= parseObject.getInt("score");
    Integer i =new Integer(score);
    t1.setText(i.toString());
}
});
```

and here is the Logcat:

```
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.salebook/com.example.salebook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at com.example.salebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-28 09:59:10.552: E/AndroidRuntime(773):  ... 11 more
```

Also, when i am on debugging mode, i see that  the objectId is null ,although i can see in the server that the object uploded succesfully with problem and it has a valid objectId.

Also, when i look in the gameScore object in eclipse i can see that it has the same objectId as in the server , however again it return me null in the objectId

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening is you are executing saveInBackground which starts on a new thread. You will then immediately call query.getInBackground with a null objectId. You need to wait and call query.getInBackground AFTER the done call in gameScore.saveInBackground.

I would recommend moving the second call to the done function call in the gamerScore.saveInBackground execution above. Also you must consider that the save may fail so you will want to catch the exception as follows:

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> items, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
       //execute query here
    } else {
       //handle exception here
    }
```

}